# Hochschild Serre Spectral sequence

Tags: group-theory, homology-cohomology

I am reading Hochschild Serre Spectral sequence from Group Theory I by M Suzuki Page 213. I will be thankful to you if you make me understand following points to me. Following is the sequence

$0 \rightarrow H^1(G/K,A^K) \xrightarrow{\alpha}H^1(G,A)\xrightarrow{\beta}H^1(K,A)^G \xrightarrow{\gamma}H^2(G/K,A^K)$

Here $G$ is a group, $K$ a normal subgroup of $G$, $A$ a $G$-module from right, $A^K=\{a \in A|ak=a ~\text{for all}~k \in K\}$ and $H^n(G,A)$ is $n$-th cohomology group.
Also $\alpha$ is inflation, $\beta$ is restriction and $\gamma$ is transgression. I understand how $\alpha$ is injective and how $Im~\alpha=Ker~\beta$. But I do not understand two points:

$(1)$ how $\gamma$ is defined, that is how a member of $H^1(K,A)$ induces a member of $H^2(G/K,A^K)$

$(2)$ how $Im~ \beta \subseteq Ker ~\gamma$.